# css width with an inline-block element

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to make a layout like this. All the banners have static dimensions and a bottom margin. And the article needs padding. The problem is the value of the width property of article. After locating the banners, I want to give the rest of the entire page width to article element. Here is my code:

```css
#SidePane {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.SideBanner {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 157px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
#SiteEye {
  width: ???????????????????????;
  height: 700px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #4F2412;
  background-color: #F9F6F4;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="SiteCenter">

  <div id="SiteEye">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="SidePane">
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="images/banners/b1.jpg" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="images/banners/b2.jpg" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="images/banners/b3.jpg" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="images/banners/b4.jpg" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: Comment on Bhojendra's answer

There is another way, it involves using `box-sizing:border-box;`, one of the most useful additions to CSS, like, ever!

I've also updated your images to use a top padding on all except the first one because you were causing some white-space at the bottom of the page with the previous method.

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box; /* Make all height/width inclusive of padding and border */
}
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#SidePane {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.SideBanner {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 175px;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#SidePane a:first-child .SideBanner {
  padding:0;  
}
#SiteEye {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: 700px;
  color: #4F2412;
  background-color: #F9F6F4;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="SiteCenter">

  <div id="SiteEye">
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>p1</p>
    <p>p2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="SidePane">
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="http://placehold.it/250x170" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="http://placehold.it/250x170" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="http://placehold.it/250x170" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <img class="SideBanner" src="http://placehold.it/250x170" alt="banner1" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Great! Now, is there some way that I can calculate the number of characters which  fit in article's box so that I can take a substring of article's content and fit it in the box? Since this is going to be a random article, it might be short or long.

Comment: @Stackcrawler There is only even a remote chance of being able to do that if you're using a monospace font. Otherwise, each character will take up a different amount of space.

Answer (score 2):

You may use calc method:

```
width: calc(100% - 250px);
```

See [can i use calc?](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) before using it for it's browser compatibility.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. I just forget to add padding property to 'SiteEye' class. So that would be something like width: calc(100% - 270px); with a paddding of 10px for SiteEye. Is there a more dynamic way to do this without hard-coding values based on dimensions and padding?